# large json file reading in nodejs with fs

Tags: node.js, json, node.js-fs, jsonstream

i have a file almost 500 MB. that is been exported from firebase. now i want to add that data into mysql.
here is the format of json file.

```
    {
    "103597192838847432678": {
        "Galaxy A213": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A231": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A233": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        }       
    },
    "103597192838847432679": {
        "Galaxy A213": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A231": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A233": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        }       
    },
   "103597192838847432690": {
        "Galaxy A213": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A231": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A233": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        }       
    }
}
```

**what is have tried is this.**

```
const express = require("express");
const db = require("../config/db");
const fs = require('fs');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const filePath = "./src/data/data.json";
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", checkServer);
router.get("/", checkServer);
router.put("/", checkServer);
router.delete("/", checkServer);
module.exports = router;

async function checkServer(req, res, next) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' } );
    //const parser = JSONStream.parse('*');
    const parser = JSONStream.parse('*.*');
    fileStream.pipe(parser);
    
    parser.on('data', (jsonObject) => {
        console.log(jsonObject);
    });
      
    parser.on('end', () => {
        console.log('All JSON objects processed.');
    });
      
    res.json({
        status: true,
        successMessage: "Server is running Here",
    });
}
```

the data that i have get in the jsonObject is

```
"Galaxy A231": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        }
```

it is missing the key of the object. how can i read the entire object like this.

```
 "103597192838847432678": {
        "Galaxy A213": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A231": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        },
        "Galaxy A233": {
           "battery_level": "61",
           "connected_Wifi": "Mobile Data",
           "email_id": "canilda28@gmail",
           "last_Location_Lat": "11.8397285",
           "last_Location_Lng": "-15.6554222",
           "last_seen": "1697471866857",
           "tokenKey":"dL2bf4bnRNGgEn"
        }       
    }
```

Comment: For this much large data; you should rely on `fs.readFile()`, rather than relying on some `streaming` solution. Also, for the soultion what happens if you use `const parser = JSONStream.parse('*');`?

Comment: it has the same results.

Comment: ok, did you consider using **[`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)**?

Comment: yes. i have added that. but that is reading it line by line and i want full json object.

Comment: @mandy8055 `fs.readFile` does not read file in `objectMode`, op wants to read each chunk  as object

Comment: i am adding it to the question what i have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `emitKey: true` parameter then you will get `key` and `value` pair object

More on [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream)

```
  async function checkServer(req, res, next) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' } );

    const parser = fileStream.pipe(JSONStream.parse([{emitKey: true}])); //here
    
    parser.on('data', async (jsonObject) => {
        parser.pause(); // this will pause the next read
        const key = jsonObject.key;
        const value = jsonObject.value;
        await somefunction(key,value); // insert into db
        console.log(key,value);
        parser.resume(); // continue to read next object
    });
      
    parser.on('end', () => {
        console.log('All JSON objects processed.');
    });
      
    res.json({
        status: true,
        successMessage: "Server is running Here",
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so muc. you save my day. i was trying on this since last 4 days

Comment: :) Happy coding

Comment: these is one thing more if you can help. how can i apply await on the parse.on function. basiclly i am inserting the data into mysql in bulk . so i want that parser.on must await for the fution to complete

Comment: You can place the logic inside the `parser.on(end)` call back, which is called after all chunks are readed

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq I have updated the answer, It will pause, insert in to db and resume read

Comment: this is an epic solution.